# CSS: "Sync" Selector Properties

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, css-selectors

My Google-fu is failing me, and I'm not quite sure if what I'm looking for even exists.

That being said, I'm trying to find a way to dynamically fetch/pull/reference a CSS property from an element in pure CSS.

I've made up a function to describe what I would like, called 'prop', which accepts a selector and a property name, and returns the value of the supplied property.

```css
div.charlie {
    background-color: black;
}

div.echo {
    color: prop(div#charlie, background-color);
}
```

My reason for doing this is that I actually will not know beforehand (without using JS) what the background-color of .charlie will be (it's an external site), but I still need the color of .echo to match and stay "in sync".

Any suggestions?

Comment: No. You cannot do this with pure CSS. A Pre-processor might offer this kind of flexibility though.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for answering. I was afraid of that :-(.

Oh well, to Javascript it is!

Comment: There was an answer, since deleted, pointing to the new Cascading Variables module which may be able to achieve something similar. Of course, it's not standardized yet, and only Firefox 31+ implements it at the moment, so it's not terribly useful at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible in pure CSS (thank you @Paulie_D).

I'd have to use Less or SASS.

Oh well :P

Comment: Is this possible with SASS these days? I mean something like the proposed `prop()` function; obviously we do have scss variables, but I mean to actually grab properties from some different selector without using variables